# Nuxt Async Data not showing return data

Tags: javascript, vue.js, google-cloud-firestore, nuxt.js

I am using Nuxt and it is recommended that we use async data for SSR.

I have this piece of code below:

```
async asyncData({ params }) {
    console.log("params ...");
    console.log(params.id);
    let asyncDataDescription = "";
    await firebase
      .firestore()
      .collection("posts")
      .where("ytid", "==", params.id)
      .get()
      .then(querySnapshot => {
        querySnapshot.forEach(doc => {
          asyncDataDescription = doc.data().ytDescription;
        });
        console.log("description ...");
        console.log(asyncDataDescription);
        return { aSyncDescription: asyncDataDescription };
      });
  },
```

In the console log, I can see the data correctly returned from firestore but somehow when I try to display the data:

```
<div>{{ aSyncDescription }}</div>
```

It is not showing.  Do I miss anything here? The page that talks about async data is here https://nuxtjs.org/api

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you see this `.then(querySnapshot => {` ?

You are returning your result to an callback function. Rewrite it like this

```
async asyncData({ params }) {
    console.log("params ...");
    console.log(params.id);
    let asyncDataDescription = "";
    let querySnapshot = await firebase
      .firestore()
      .collection("posts")
      .where("ytid", "==", params.id)
      .get()
    querySnapshot.forEach(doc => {
       asyncDataDescription = doc.data().ytDescription;
    });
    console.log("description fdkjfdk");
    console.log(asyncDataDescription);
    return { aSyncDescription: asyncDataDescription };
  },
```

Comment: got it, really puzzled by it.